# Write the value of a boolean to a file in php

Tags: php

I am trying to log some data for a bug fix of a project. I have a boolean which i need to write to a text file but for some reason the boolean is never printed below is the code that calls the function to write the log.

```
writeLog("Index: $index Create Table Headers: ". $myBoolean);
```

And below is the code of the function that actually writes to the file

```
function writeLog($message)
{
    $file = "log.txt";
    $fh = fopen($file, 'a') or die("Can't open file");
    $content = $message . "\r\n";
    fwrite($fh, $content);
    fclose($fh);
}
```

When the file is written All I am getting is

> Index: 0 Create Table Headers:

I have tried using var_export($myBoolean) but didn't make any difference

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Show us the code showing/assigning the value of `$myBoolean` ?

Comment: assuming $myBoolean (false/true) it works and writes 1 or 0 in file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
writeLog("Index: $index Create Table Headers: ". ($myBoolean ? 'true' : 'false'));
```

See [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) for the "?" ternary operator